# Flutter BetterPlayer: Set resolution of HLS video programmatically?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to set the resolution when playing HLS (.m3u8) videos in BetterPlayer programmatically?

There is the resolution selector in the video controls that works just fine but I'm not showing the UI controls in my app. There is also the `setResolution` function that takes an URL as an argument, so this is probably only useful if you have different URLs for different resolutions, which is not the case for my HLS videos.